# relation of stl iterator and array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, stl

I am not crystal clear about pointer and iterator, especially in the case of constructing vector from an array.

From the description about [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), it says

```
// the iterator constructor can also be used to construct from arrays:
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
std::vector<int> fifth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
```

in primary, it is:

```
#include <vector>

int arr[ARR_LEN] = { /* Array elements */ };
std::vector<int> vecInt(arr, arr + ARR_LEN);
```

does it use the following constructor?

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
        const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

If so, then here, is a pointer (for array) treated into an random access iterator, then as input iterator? How does the compiler do this? Considering iterators from other containers, what is the type of this iterator, e.g. "array[int]"::iterator?

```
int arr[N] = {};
for (int i= 0; i<N; i++) {}
```

instead of the above, can I do something like as follows?

```
for (ItorType it=arr; it!=arr+N; ++it) { ... }
```

Comment: Pointers to elements of an array satisfy the input iterator requirements. That is all that is needed for this particular constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it use the following constructor?

Yes.

> If so, then here, is a pointer (for array) treated into an random access iterator, then as input iterator?

Yes.

> How does the compiler do this?

Concepts like `InputIterator` are informal specifications of how a type must behave; to be an `InputIterator`, it must support indirection (`*it`) to access a value, and increment (`++it` and `it++`) to move to the next value. To be a `RandomAccessIterator`, it must support these operations, plus a few more such as addition and subtraction. Pointers meet these requirements, so can be used wherever an iterator is required.

> Considering iterators from other containers, what is the type of this iterator, e.g. "array[int]"::iterator?

You'd use a pointer, `int*`, to iterate over an array, `int[]`. When used as a function argument (as here), or used in arithmetic (such as `arr+N`), the array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

> instead of the above, can I do something like as follows?

Yes. `ItorType` would be the corresponding pointer type, `int*`. In C++11, we have `begin` and `end` functions to get the beginning and end of any range including arrays:

```
for (auto it = std::begin(arr); it != std::end(arr); ++it)
```

and also range-based loops:

```
for (int i : arr)
```

Answer (score 5):

The iterator template arguments are not specific class. In fact, the names have no real impact on the compilation process. Instead, they refer to specific *concepts* which specify the methods available for a specific iterator. Any RandomAccessIterator also has to be an InputIterator: the RandomAccessIterator concept is a refinement of the InputIterator concept.

The compiler really just passes these arguments, in your case pointers, through. Pointers implement the RandomAccessIterator concept, i.e., they can be readily used with the `std::vector<...>` constructor you quoted. BTW, the proper way to write this initialization is

```
std::vector<int> vecInt(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

The function templates `begin()` and `end()` were added to the latest version of C++ and deduce the size of statically sized arrays. Both approaches used to determine the size in your example are problematic in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
        const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

The compiler will use this constructor simply because it a two argument constructor with the same type for both arguments.

It doesn't have to be that the arguments are iterators. For instance if you write

```
vector<int> x(3.0, 1.0);
```

the compiler will try to use the same constructor (which would then lead to compile errors because doubles can't be used like iterators).

Comment: `vector<int> x(3,1);` does not use the same constructor, and the constructor does not have to do any work to figure it out.  The compiler figures it out, and calls the constructor which is the better match.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Which constructor is the better match?

Comment: `vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I've certainly seen STL implementations where it was done in the manner I described. But maybe I'm out of date. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it uses aforementioned constructor and treats pointer as random access iterator. Since all RandomAccessIterators also are InputIterators ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/)). Compiler can do this cause Iterator classes defines **valid operators on itself** in terms of static interfaces. No matter how they implemented and actually means. Only type correctness and interface correctness plays their roles.

You could `typedef int * ItorType` and your last sample would compiled and worked very well.